# How To Clear The User Type In All The Blank In The Form On PHP After The Submit Executed?

Tags: javascript, php, function, email, dom

I am struggling to **clear** all the **user inputs** in the blank within the form after the submit executed.

To do that, I am trying to put a function named `submit()` onto a ***PHP*** file named `send.php`, but I do not know whether my function code can be used in the PHP file.

Now I could create the system which send a form to my email account on a new tab on a browser. After closing the tab (thankyou.php), I can still see the user inputs in the blank on the contact page.

What I want to do is that after the user sent the form, they can be back to the contact page without any inputs in the blanks on the contact page.

The flow of the process is contact.php -> send.php -> open the new tab -> Open thankyou.php -> close the thankyou.php -> Clear the inputs in the blanks on contact.php

```
header('location: thankyou.php');

echo '<script type="text/javascript" language="Javascript">history.go(-1);</script>';

$_POST = submit();

function submit($name, $company, $phone, $email, $message) {
    $inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
    for(var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
        if(!inputs[i].getAttribute('type') == null){
            inputs[i] = "";
        }
    }
    return submit($name, $company, $phone, $email, $message);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `contact.php`:

```
<form onsubmit="return clearFields()">
```

Javascript:

```
function clearFields(){
  setTimeout(function(){
    //input.value = ""
    //Clear the inputs
  },2000);
  return true;
}
```

Comment: I did it, but it did not change although I fixed it several times. Thank you

Comment: Then you should use ajax.

Answer (score 0):

Clearing inputs with PHP is not possible without refreshing the page. When a page is loaded you can only modify things with javascript. You can clear all form fields after form submission like this:

```
  document.getElementById("myForm").reset();
```

Comment: I did, but it does not change. I think I will put the code which clears when a user click the blank.

Comment: Did you set id for your form?